# Counting words with regular expression "\S+"

Tags: java, regex

Why does `wordCount` end up being 1, rather than 5, in the code below?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pattern wordCountRegularExpression = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
        final Matcher matcher = wordCountRegularExpression
                .matcher("one two three four five");
        int wordCount = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            wordCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("wordCount: " + wordCount);
    }
}
```

Doesn't the pattern "\S+" match a word, since it means one or more non-space characters?

This does work by the way:

```
    final Pattern wordCountRegularExpression = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b");
```

But I still don't understand why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: @Jens the backslash in the pattern must be escaped in the string literal.

Comment: I ran it and got 5. http://ideone.com/bxe00  Try cleaning your project or recompiling?

Comment: @Jens, no, `"\\S"` is correct.  `"\S"` is not a valid string literal in Java.

Comment: `String[] words = mystring.split("\\s+");` could also be useful, and shorter.  (\\s is space, tab or newline.)

Comment: This works for me too. Are you sure something else is not wrong with your env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't the pattern "\S+" match a word, since it means one or more non-space characters?

[Yes.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

in java 7, the following pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("\\S+");
```

Will not count word, but spaces.

So, it should return 4 for the input: "one two three four five", since it have 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using to separate the words.  When I copy the code from your question into my editor, I see plain old spaces (`U+0020`), but when I viewsource the page I see non-breaking spaces (`U+00A0`).  Java doesn't recognize the NBSP as a whitespace character.

Now the question is why am I seeing NBSP's in the string literal, but nowhere else?  And why are they being converted to spaces when I copy/paste?  Is anyone else seeing that?